# Using Morphia or Mongo java driver to check if a query matches a document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, morphia, mongo-java-driver

I probably have not a very typical usecase, but what I want to achieve is the following:
given a Morphia/MongoQuery (essentially a DBObject) I want to know whether is matches a document (another DBObject). If I put this document into mongodb collection and run a query, and this query returns this document, I know it matches. But is it possible to achieve this without putting that document into the database? Or maybe I can create a virtual/in-memory collection with just that document, and throw it away once I've done the matching?

Thanks in advance!

**UPD**:
Actually it's not directly related to mongodb, but I just wanted to "abuse" the expressiveness of a query language and the fact that I'm quite familiar with mongodb/morphia.

My usecase is: assume I have an entity in memory like:

> { age: 23, gender: "F", country: "GBP"}

and I want to see if that entity matches a predefined state of rules.
E.g.:

> (age > 20 AND country IN ["USA", "DEU"]) OR (age > 21 AND gender =
>   "M")

I could come up with my own DSL, write a parser for it and then write a matcher. Or, my hope was, I could reuse query language and query engine in MongoDB to be able to "query" a virtual collection with just that 1 document and see whether that query returns any results. That would save me quite some efforts.

Comment: What do you think you are asking? Morphia is an Object Mapper sitting on top of the MongoDB Java Driver. The purpose is to talk to a MongoDB database and nothing else. You cannot use the same library for a different purpose. You might be talking about a "cache", but it's really unclear in the wording of your question. You would probably be better off showing an example of what you think you want to do and getting others input on ways to achieve it, rather than presuming you know the best way to do it. Particularly when what you think you want does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I just updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems not possible to do so (or I just didn't figure out a way to achieve this), I came up with an alternative solution and used JEXL (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/)